# Is it possible to swap charisma modifier to int or wis when binding outsiders as a wizard?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, wizard

I want to build a demon-hunting wizard and just read through the rules for binding outsiders. Here I found:

> Once there, the outsider can pit its spell resistance as a check
>   against the  caster’s  level,  attempt  to  flee via  dimensional 
>   travel,  or  attempt to overcome the spell by imposing its
>   spiritual presence with a Charisma  check  (DC  15  +  1/2  the 
>   caster’s  level + the caster’s Charisma modifier).

Since usually wizards have not a very good charisma modifier I was wondering if there is a way to change this over to Int or Wis but could not find anything. Anyone who knows if this is possbile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RAW, no. The DC for the outsider is Charisma based, and I'm unaware of any archetypes or prestige classes that change this.

Given that DC base is 15 instead of 10 it seems likely the designers were aware of how low most Wizards' charismas scores would be for this sort of thing, and may have intentionally given Sorcerers an advantage on this to fit the archetypal "sorcerers binding powers potentially beyond their control" image.